# coverage report not displayed on jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job pipeline that executes this -

1. Execute nosetests -

   nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=report/nosetests.xml --with-coverage --cover-package="testproject" --cover-html tests/unit/*
2. This creates the nosetests report under report/nosetests.xml
3. It also creates a /cover directory with the coverage report.
4. When I check the jenkins page for that job. The testresults are displayed but the coverage report.

[image]

Also, here is my pipeline -

```
stage ('Unit Tests') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    #. venv/bin/activate
                    export PATH=${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin:${PATH}
                    make unittest || true
                """
            }

            post {
                always {
                    junit keepLongStdio: true, testResults: 'report/nosetests.xml'
                    publishHTML target: [
                        reportDir: 'cover/',
                        reportFiles: 'index.html',
                        reportName: 'Coverage Report - Unit Test'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```